# On Bitbucket, how can I click on a source file and be directed to the URL of the current version of the file instead of a commit version of the file?

Tags: bitbucket

When I click on a source file on the Bitbucket web interface, I am directed to a URL something like the following:

```
https://bitbucket.org/team/someproject/src/ab59759347f7298e875t9c5764d3228d7124aee8/someproject/api.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default
```

I need to be directed to something like the following instead:

```
https://bitbucket.org/team/someproject/src/master/someproject/api.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default
```

How can I change Bitbucket settings to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You've already done it in your example. The commit hash will always take you to a specific revision, but if you replace that with the branch name then it will take you to the head or tip of that branch.

Comment: Hey there. No, I need to be able to click on a file in the web interface and to be brought to that head version. I need the interface to use the appropriate URL. I'm not gonna manually change links.